# Opening 2 or more files on an Ubuntu file share from Windows causes file handle to be closed

Tags: mount, samba, shared-folders

*Ubuntu noob here, please go easy. :)*

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 box acting as a file/media server, used by two Windows laptops (7 and 8.1), an Android phone and a smart TV. The Ubuntu box has 4 extra hard drives, each shared separately, and all are formatted as NTFS.

Until recently, everything has been working fine. For the last few weeks (including before the upgrade to 16.04, when I was on 15.10) however, I have found that when I have one file open on any device from any of the file shares on the Ubuntu box, then if I open another file on the same device from the same file share, then an error will occur on either the first or the second files, where it appears that Ubuntu has closed the file handle. I then have to reopen whatever file it was that had the error, which usually works, but sometimes then causes the same type of error on the other open file.

The same issue continues if I try to open more than 2 files - and it's seemingly at random as to which of the already open files will experience the error.

This issue is most readily obvious when listening to music or watching videos, however I've checked and it also happens with .DOC and .PDF files and presumably all other types as well.

Here is an example scenario:
I am listening to an .MP3 from share #1 in Nightingale, and then open a .AVI (also from share #1) in VLC.  VLC will give an error:

> File reading failed:
>   VLC could not read the file (Bad file descriptor).

If I then try to re-start the video file in VLC, almost always Nightingale will have an error and skip straight to the next track.

If I instead have one file open on share #1, and open a second file on share #2, there is no problem, everything works fine.  If I then open a third file on share #2, the problem occurs.

To me it feels like Ubuntu has some kind of file-handle limit going on for the file shares, and it's set extremely low. I've done some basic searching on settings, but haven't seen anything obvious so far.

Here is what I have tried, all to no avail:

- Applied all the latest updates
- Upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04

In testing, I have confirmed that:

- it happens on either of the Windows laptops
- it does NOT happen directly on the Ubuntu box, only when accessing via file shares.

Although I occasionally install new things on the Ubuntu box, I don't recall doing so in the days before the problem start - with the exception of the normal Ubuntu updates available in Software Updater.  My fstab file has definitely not changed in this timeframe.

Please let me know what kind of information I can provide to help troubleshoot.

As an aside, the Ubuntu box does have one semi-frequent (~daily) error that comes up about smbd, but it's been happening ever since I first set up the shares 2 years ago, so I don't think it's relevant to this very recent problem starting. Here is the bug tracker for it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1514766

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the problem has now gone away after I applied newly available updates.

Here is a list of what was installed today - presumably it's one of the samda updates that fixed the problem.

[image: Updates installed]